# The best way to Complex query in linq

Tags: c#, linq

**The best way to change below in Linq Lamda**

Category will be unique across Location to its base location. And I should load the category of immediate location first. If there is no category with that name then should load its immediate parent. Also I have 3 level in location.

```
Id  Name        Location
==========================
1   Breakfast   India 
2   Breakfast   TamilNadu 
3   Breakfast   Chennai 
4   Dinner      India 
5   Dinner      TamilNadu 
6   Lunch       Chennai 
7   Combo       TamilNadu
```

(India -1 level, TamilNadu -2 level, Chennai -2 level)
And I need result as

```
3   Breakfast   Chennai
5   Dinner      TamilNadu
6   Lunch       Chennai
7   Combo       TamilNadu
```

My SQL Query is :

```
Declare @locationId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '7504657E-FEE4-E411-9505-BC305BB6199F'

BEGIN
    DECLARE @Locations TABLE(Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,LocationLevel int)

Set NoCount On

INSERT INTO @Locations 
SELECT AccountId,0 FROM Locations WHERE id = @locationId AND AccountId is not null
UNION  
SELECT FranchiseId,1 FROM Locations WHERE id = @locationId AND FranchiseId is not null
UNION  
SELECT @locationId,2

Set NoCount Off

SELECT C.* 
FROM Categories c
Join @Locations l on c.LocationId = l.Id
WHERE c.IsDeleted = 0 
AND (c.LocationId = @locationId OR (c.IsPublished = 1 And c.Status = 1))
AND l.LocationLevel = 
(
    Select Max(l1.LocationLevel) 
    From Categories c1 
    JOIN @Locations l1 on c1.LocationId = l1.Id 
    WHERE c1.Name=c.Name AND c1.IsDeleted = 0
)
Order by C.Name
END
```

My current query was :

```
var categoryes = await CategoryRepository.GetCategoryForContext(ParentLocationIdList.Keys);
```

Here ParentLocationIdList contains location id and level(1|2|3) for selected location

```
var result = categoryes.Join(ParentLocationIdList, c => c.LocationId, l => l.Key, (c, l) => new
            {
                Category = c,
                Level = l.Value,
                Name = c.Name
            });

            categoryes = result.GroupBy(g => g.Name).Select(s => s.First(d => d.Level == s.Max(m => m.Level)).Category).ToList();

            return categoryes;
```

Comment: Is your current lamba expression not working or you're looking for a better approach?

Comment: Hi @ANewGuyInTown Thanks for reply. The query is working perfectly. But I am looking for better approack